# How to examine TCP traffic to a particular port on unix?

Tags: shell, unix, tcpdump

I have an application, which goes and hit an Web Service and displays the data.

The port to which the application establishes a TCP connection I discovered by using the `lsof` command.

But I'm not sure how to capture packets destined for that port to see what all data the application sends and receives.

Comment: Your terminology and problem description kind of clashed with a completely different problem.  By editing, I'm afraid I might have made the question rather daft, but hopefully you should be able to obtain some good beginner-level answers now.  Unfortunately, the answers you already received were for that other question.  Feel free to revert if that's what you really meant.

Comment: You should probably simply visit http://wireshark.org/

Answer (score -1):

Open a TCP connection to port 42 of host.example.com, using port 31337 as the source port, with a timeout of 5 seconds:

```
$ nc -p 31337 -w 5 host.example.com 42
```

Open a UDP connection to port 53 of host.example.com:

```
$ nc -u host.example.com 53
```

`nc` utility

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/nc.htm

Answer (score -2):

If you have root or pseudo root access...

snoop to port

Or even google the truss command if you have the PID but i guess you just want the port itself. Hope this helps.